# How can i attach a listener in a base object to the top/extending object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, listener

The goal : i want to attach a listener in a base class to the top-most instance of inheritance.

The problem : the listener is attaching to the base class; thus, with every new call, an additional listener is attached.

Details : as the code snippets below show, i'm using require and backbone to create my objects - one object per file. `PrimaryObj` extends `midObj`, which extends `baseObj`, which extends `Backbone.Model`.

In the view (template) are a field and a button which, when clicked, calls `loadThing`. The user can fill in the field with new values, then click on the button each time to load new data.

However, every time a new object is built, the attributes are correctly assigned, but it's like i get a *reference* to the `baseObj` (which already has a listener attached), instead of a new clean copy/clone (which would have no listeners attached ... yet).

I *thought* that the reference to `this` in `baseObj` would refer to the primary/extending object (`primaryObj`), not `baseObj` itself (which is where it *seems* like it's being attached).

How can i attach a listener in the base object (`baseObj`) to JUST the top object (`primaryObj`)?

Thanks!

main.js  ---------------

```
require([ 'backbone', 'routers/router' ], function (Backbone, Router) {
    window.DISPATCHER = _.clone(Backbone.Events); 
    var router = new Router(); 
    Backbone.history.start(); 
});
```

baseObj.js  ---------------

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore' ], function (Backbone, _) {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize : function (p_thing) {
          this.listenTo(window.DISPATCHER, "message",  function (p_data) { /*  some cool functionality  */ });
        }
    });
});
```

midObj.js  ---------------

```
define([ 'models/baseObj' ], function (BaseOBJ) {
    return BaseOBJ.extend({
        initialize : function () {
          BaseOBJ.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
});
```

primaryObj.js  ---------------

```
define([ 'models/midObj' ], function (MidOBJ) {
    return MidOBJ.extend({
        initialize : function (p_id) {
          this.set({'ref' : p_id});
          MidOBJ.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
});
```

myView.js  ---------------

```
define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'primaryObj' ], function($, _, Backbone, MPrimary) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        events     : { 'click .bLoad' : 'loadThing', },
        initialize : function (p_options) {
          this.listenTo(Backbone, 'obj:loaded', function () { this.render("device"); });
          this.model = {};
        },
        loadThing  : function (p_id) { this.model = new MDevice(p_id); },
        render     : function (p_target) { /* ... */ },
        template   : _.template(TModelTest)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was discovered that the problem, as posted, was not really the problem. The listener was being handled correctly but was never getting cleaned up; thus the 'old'/original object was getting garbage collected, but it's listener was (correctly) not.

As stated in the problem, `this.listenTo(Backbone, ...)` created a listener related to the object on the *Backbone* object, not the *created* object; the solution, then, was to explicitly remove the listener on the backbone object.